# To transfer ERC20 tokens (using Web3js), is it necessary to implement web.eth.Contract?

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, abi

I'm kind of new to Ethereum network. I used to implement Stellar before.
I have successfully implemented my JavaScript app to transfer Eth already.
Therefore, I want to expand my above app to accept/transfer ERC20 tokens on the markets, by still using web3js, I wonder

1. Do I have to implement web3.eth.Contract for my app wallet to achieve ERC20 tokens compatible ?
2. If not, is there any other easy ways to implement this ?
3. What is the `SOME_ERC20_FILE.json` file as shown in code below (that is related to ABI) ? Where can I get an example of this JSON file ?

   ```
   const fs = require('fs');
   const parsedFile = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(SOME_ERC20_FILE.json));
   const abi = parsedFile.abi;    
   const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, 0x012345678912345678012345678012345678012);
   ```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This might help](https://shawntabrizi.com/crypto/ethereum-token-contract-abi-web3-erc-20-human-standard-tokens/) to get started on ERC-20 Tokens with Web3.js.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use ERC20 tokens you will want to construct a `Contract` object for the smart contract corresponding to each ERC20 token. You can then use the methods of the object to do things like `myContract.methods.balanceOf(addr)`

All ERC20 tokens must (by definition) follow the ERC20 ABI, which you can get [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Contract-ERC20-ABI). The `SOME_ERC20_FILE.json` in your example is just a file containing the ABI. You can read it from a file or just hard code it.